# Regex positive lookbehind in Google Sheets

Tags: regex, google-sheets

I have a Google Sheet with a list of transactions. I need to isolate up to three words or numbers in the column E that come after the word "end" in the column D. The proper regex function should be the positive lookbehind, but it is not supported in RE2 (source: [Using positive-lookahead (?=regex) with re2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30305542/using-positive-lookahead-regex-with-re2)).

This formula returns an error in GSheets:

```
=REGEXEXTRACT(D1;"(?<=end\s)(\w+)")
```

So my conclusion is that regex is a dead end in this case.

How do I obtain the requested result in GSheets?

Comment: Can't you just use `=REGEXEXTRACT(D1;"end\s*(\w+)")`? Could you please provide an example of the string in D1 and expected result? If you need 1, 2 or 3 whitespace separated words, you will need something like `"end\s*(\w+(?:\s+\w+){0,2})"`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You may use a capturing group in your regex to make `REGEXEXTRACT` return just that captured part:

```
=REGEXEXTRACT(D1;"end\s*(\w+)")
```

If you need to return 1, 2 or 3 whitespace-separated words after `end`, use

```
=REGEXEXTRACT(D1;"end\s*(\w+(?:\s+\w+){0,2})")
```

See the [online demo](https://regex101.com/r/9mqYQm/1) (Golang regex also uses RE2).

**Details**

- `end` - `end`
- `\s*` - 0+ whitespaces
- `(\w+(?:\s+\w+){0,2})` - Capturing group 1:

  - `\w+` - 1+ word chars  (letters, digits or `_`)
  - `(?:\s+\w+){0,2}` - 0, 1 or 2 occurrences of

    - `\s+` - 1+ whitespaces
    - `\w+` - 1+ word chars.

Answer (score 5):

If you desperately need a different RegEx backend other than RE2, you can use an App Script to create a custom function that uses JS to evaluate the RegEx.

1. Click **Tools** > **Script Editor**.
2. In the editor add your custom JS RegEx function. You can use the example below.
3. Give it a name `JS_REGEXEXTRACT` is a good option.
4. Click save button in the toolbar.
5. Go back to the browser tab with your Sheet in it, and replace `REGEXEXTRACT` with `JS_REGEXEXTRACT`.

You now have a working JS base RegEx option. It will not be as fast as the RE2 implementation, so be careful on large datasets with complex expressions.

```js
/**
 * Extracts matching substrings according to a regular expression using JS not RE2.
 *
 * @param {"abcdefg"} text The input text.
 * @param {"c.*f"} regular_expression The first part of `text` that matches this expression will be returned.
 * @return Extracts matching substrings according to a regular expression.
 * @customfunction
 */
function JS_REGEXEXTRACT(text, regular_expression) {
  if (text.length < 1) {
    return null;
  }
  matches = text.match(new RegExp(regular_expression))
  if (matches && matches.length >= 1) {
    return matches[1];
  }
  return matches;
}
```