# Error parsing regexp: invalid or unsupported Perl syntax: `?=`

Tags: regex, go, regex-lookarounds

When I try this regex in Golang I'm getting a regex parsing error.

panic: regexp: Compile(`.+?(?=someText)`): error parsing regexp: invalid or unsupported Perl syntax: `(?=`

```
regexp.MustCompile(`.+?(?=someText)`)
```

This is probably something to do with lookarounds, but I'm not sure about what the solution is as I don't have much experience with regex.

Comment: The `(?=pattern)` is a legitimate [lookahead](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlretut#Looking-ahead-and-looking-behind) assertion -- in Perl, what you tagged (for some reason?). The whole pattern would be a way to get the engine to the place just before `someText` (having "consumed" whatever precedes that zero-width "place"). I don't know how it goes in Go though ... but it appears that it just isn't supported?  Perhaps syntax for it is different?

Comment: At [this doc](https://github.com/google/re2/wiki/Syntax) it says 'not supported' for that ...  and see [this page](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30305542/4653379), which practically answers the question. One of the answers also offers an alternative

Comment: It's basically trying to tell you "you thought Go supported this Perl regex extension, but this is not Perl".

Comment: The perl tag is for the perl *programming language*, not regular expressions in other languages.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Judging by the first question mark, it seems like you're trying to get the substring before the first occurrence of `someText`. If that is in fact the case, you could use this as an alternative:

```
package main
import "strings"

func main() {
   s := "March someText April someText"
   n := strings.Index(s, "someText")
   s = s[:n]
   println(s == "March ")
}
```

https://golang.org/pkg/strings#Index