# RE2 Nested Regex Group Match

Tags: c++, regex, re2

I have a RE2 regex as following

```cpp
const re2::RE2 numRegex("(([0-9]+),)+([0-9])+");
std::string inputStr;
inputStr="apple with make,up things $312,412,3.00");
RE2::Replace(&inputStr, numRegex, "$1$3");
cout << inputStr;
```

Expected

```
apple with make,up,things $3124123.00
```

I was trying to remove the `,` in the recognized number, `$1` would only match `312` but not `412` part. Wondering how to extract the recursive pattern in the group.

Note that RE2 doesn't support lookahead (see [Using positive-lookahead (?=regex) with re2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30305542)) and the solutions I found all use lookaheads.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not really clear on what you want to achieve. You simply want to remove commas from numbers? I'd match on the comma-based number format, then a second pass to remove the numbers.

Comment: You are repeating a capture group, which will have the last value of the iteration.

Comment: You just want to remove commas between digits. Use `std::regex numRegex(R"((\d),(?=\d))");` and the replace with `$1`, `regex_replace(inputStr, numRegex, "$1")`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**RE2 based solution**

As RE2 does not support lookarounds, there is no pure single-pass regex solution.

You can have a workaround (as usual, when no solution is available): replace the string twice with `(\d),(\d)` regex and `$1$2` substitution:

```cpp
const re2::RE2 numRegex(R"((\d),(\d))");
std::string inputStr("apple with make,up things $312,412,3.00");
RE2::Replace(&inputStr, numRegex, "$1$2");
RE2::Replace(&inputStr, numRegex, "$1$2"); // <- Second pass to remove commas in 1,2,3,4 like strings
std::cout << inputStr;
```

**C++ `std::regex` based solution:**

You can remove the commas between digits using

```cpp
std::string inputStr("apple with make,up things $312,412,3.00");
std::regex numRegex(R"((\d),(?=\d))"); 
std::cout << regex_replace(inputStr, numRegex, "$1") << "\n";
// => apple with make,up things $3124123.00
```

See the [C++ demo](https://ideone.com/HgHRLL). Also, see the [regex demo here](https://regex101.com/r/Wy08AX/1).

*Details*:

- `(\d)` - Capturing group 1 (`$1`): a digit
- `,` - a comma
- `(?=\d)` - a positive lookahead that requires a digit immediately to the right of the current location.

Comment: Thanks for the nit solution. As we need to use RE2, it doesn't support lookahead unfortunately.

Comment: @MG. I added a workaround for RE2.

Answer (score 1):

In the pattern that you tried, you are repeating the outer group `(([0-9]+),)+` which will then contain the value of the last iteration where it can match a 1+ digits and a comma.

The last iteration will capture `412,` and `312,` will only be matched.

---

You are using `regex`, but as an alternative if you have boost available, you could make use of the `\G` anchor which can get iterative matches asserting the position at the end of the previous match and replace with an empty string.

```
(?:\$|\G(?!^))\d+\K,(?=\d)
```

The pattern matches:

- `(?:` Non capture group

  - `\$` match `$`
  - `|` Or
  - `\G(?!^)` Assert the position at the end of the previous match, not at the start
- `)` Close non capture group
- `\d+\K` Match 1+ digits and forget what is matched so far
- `,(?=\d)` Match a comma and assert a digit directly to the right

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/OSjAam/1)

```
#include<iostream>
#include <string>
#include <boost/regex.hpp>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    std::string inputStr = "apple with make,up things $312,412,3.00";
    boost::regex numRegex("(?:\\$|\\G(?!^))\\d+\\K,(?=\\d)");  
    std::string result = boost::regex_replace(inputStr, numRegex, "");
    std::cout << result << std::endl;
}
```

Output

```
apple with make,up things $3124123.00
```