# Removing lowercase letter before an uppercase letter

Tags: regex, re2

I was trying to replace all the small case letters that come before an uppercase letter on BigQuery.

For example:-

```
string = aDepartment of test, kHospital of test
```

After replacement

```
Department of test, Hospital of test
```

I have made the regex `[a-z](?=[A-Z])`. This regex works fine on regex101. But when I use this regex on BigQuery, it shows `Cannot parse regular expression: invalid perl operator: (?=` error.

I'm not able to understand what this error is about.
Can anyone look into this regex so that it can work on BigQuery?

Comment: Did you read the BigQuery manual on regular expressions, or just expect it to support what you want it to support?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Lookarounds are [not supported in RE2 library](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30305934/3832970).

You can use

```sql
regexp_replace(col, r'[a-z]([A-Z])', r'\1')
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/1f8tC2/1).

*Details*:

- `[a-z]` - an ASCII lowercase letter
- `([A-Z])` - Group 1 (`\1`): an ASCII uppercase letter.

Comment: This works great. Didn't know about this wildcard `\1`

Comment: @SHIVAMSINGH They are also called "placeholders" or "[replacement backreferences](https://www.regular-expressions.info/replacebackref.html)".

Answer (score 0):

"Unfortunately, Google BigQuery is using the RE2 expression library, which is not currently supporting either positive or negative lookaheads"

I think you can ask regex101 to use a different engine so you're debugging something compatible with BigQuery, where you'll see `?=` is in error. If you don't *need* the lookahead, you can simply remove these two characters, just keep in mind you'll now be capturing that captial letter (so you'll need to add it back in your replace).